# Envio anexo função mail php

Tags: php, funções, email

Boa tarde pessoal, sempre uso o PHPMailer para envio de emails, mas não sei porque dessa vez não consegui configurar no servidor. Então estou utilizando o codigo abaixo para enviar e a questão é que se não colocar o headers ele envia as mensagens com os dados do POST mas não vai enviar o anexo corretamente e se eu colocar o headers ele envia somente a imagem, não sei o que esta acontecendo de errado, já tentei de tudo, segue o codigo, se alguém puder me orientar , agradeço desde já!

```
$arquivo = $_FILES["attachment"];


$boundary = "XYZ-".date("dmYis")."-ZYX";
$fp = fopen($arquivo["tmp_name"], "rb"); // abre o arquivo enviado
$anexo = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo["tmp_name"])); // calcula o tamanho
$anexo = base64_encode($anexo); // codifica o anexo em base 64
fclose($fp); // fecha o arquivo

// cabeçalho do email
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers .= "boundary=".$boundary."\r\n";
$headers .= "$boundary\n";

// email
$mensagem  = "--$boundary\n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n";
$mensagem .= "Nome:  $name \r\n";
$mensagem .= "E-mail:  $email \r\n";
$mensagem .= "Cidade:  $city \r\n";
$mensagem .= "Estado:  $state \r\n";
$mensagem .= "Mensagem:  $message \r\n";
$mensagem .= "--$boundary \n";

if( empty ($arquivo[0] ) ){
$mensagem .= "Content-Type: " .$arquivo["type"]. "; name=\"\" " .$arquivo['name']. " \n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 \n";
$mensagem .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"\" " .$arquivo['name']. " \r\n";
$mensagem .= "$anexo \n";
$mensagem .= "--$boundary \n";
 }
// enviar o email

$sendMail = mail($sender_email, $default_subject, $mensagem, $headers);

  if( !$sendMail ){
    echo json_encode( array( 
      'alert'  => 'error',
      'message' => $error_message ));
  } else {
    echo json_encode( array( 'alert' => 'success' , 'message' => $success_message ) );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para os meus clientes eu uso assim, voce pode adaptar no seu que tenho certeza que vai funcionar sim.

```
<?php


$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
$idade = $_POST['idade'];
$formacao = $_POST['formacao'];
$formacaox = $_POST['formacaox'];
$horariod = $_POST['horariod'];
$salario = $_POST['salario'];
$apresentacao = $_POST['apresentacao'];
$obs = $_POST['obs'];
$exp = $_POST['exp'];
$ult = $_POST['ult'];


$nomes=$_FILES['files']['name'];
$nome_temp= $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
$tamanho= $_FILES['files']['size'];

$meudiretorio = "/tmp/";

move_uploaded_file($nome_temp, $meudiretorio.$nomes);


require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Host = "ssl://mail.servidor.com.br"; // Seu endereço de host SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Define que será utilizada a autenticação -  Mantenha o valor "true"
$mail->Port = 465; // Porta de comunicação SMTP - Mantenha o valor "587"
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // Define se é utilizado SSL/TLS - Mantenha o valor "false"
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; // Define se, por padrão, será utilizado TLS - Mantenha o valor "false"
$mail->Username = 'servidor@servido.com.br'; // Conta de email existente e ativa em seu domínio
$mail->Password = '123456'; // Senha da sua conta de email

// DADOS DO REMETENTE
$mail->Sender = "servidor@servidor.com.br"; // Conta de email existente e ativa em seu domínio
$mail->From = "servidor@servidor.com.br"; // Sua conta de email que será remetente da mensagem
$mail->FromName = "Formulario de Contato"; // Nome da conta de email

// DADOS DO DESTINATÁRIO
$mail->AddAddress('cv@servidor.com.br', 'Nome - Recebe1'); // Define qual conta de email receberá a mensagem
//$mail->AddAddress('recebe2@dominio.com.br'); // Define qual conta de email receberá a mensagem
//$mail->AddCC('copia@dominio.net'); // Define qual conta de email receberá uma cópia
//$mail->AddBCC('copiaoculta@dominio.info'); // Define qual conta de email receberá uma cópia oculta
//
$mail->Subject = "Cv formulario site";
$mail->msgHTML("<html>De: {$nome}<br>Email: {$email} <br>Telefone: {$telefone} <br>Endereco: {$endereco} <br> Idade: {$idade} <br>Formacao: {$formacao} <br> Formacao Extra: {$formacaox} Horario Disponivel: {$horariod} <br> Salario: {$salario} <br> Apresentacao: {$apresentacao} <br> Observacao: {$obs} <br> Experiencia: {$exp} <br> Ultima Remuneracao: {$ult}  </html>");
$mail->addAttachment($meudiretorio.$nomes);
$mail->AltBody = "De: {$nome}\nEmail: {$email}\nTelefone: {$telefone}\nEndereco: {$endereco}\n Idade: {$idade}\nFormacao {$formacao}\n Formacao Extra: {$formacaox}\n Horario Disponivel: {$horariod}\n Salario: {$salario}\n Apresentacao: {$apresentacao}\n Observacao: {$obs} \n Experiencia: {$exp} \n Ultima Remuneracao: {$ult}";

if ($mail->send()) {

    header("Location: sucesso.php");
}else {
 echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
  echo "<b>Detalhes do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  header("Location: contato.php");
}



?>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas como eu disse problema esta no servidor que não esta aceitando usar phpmailer, mas eu corrige o problema desse, obrigado